# HTML Video not working on Visualforce Rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, video

I have a Visualforce page with a series of videos on it. I'm trying to create a filter for it, so that the videos that display on this page changes when you click and item in the filter. Everything works, except that when I re-render my "webinarBlock" page block, the actual video doesn't show and I get the "Your browser does not support the video tag" error that I added. The video does show when the page initially loads. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Here's my code:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="mainDetail" id="webinarBlock">
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
           <apex:repeat id="webinars" value="{!bwList}" var="b" first="0"> 
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="eachBlock">
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <div id="adnblogtitle" style="text-align:center">{!b.Title}</div>
                          <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(isBlank(b.Video))}" style="text-align:center; display:block;">
                               <video width="400" height="300" controls="true">
                                    <source src="{!b.Video}" type="video/mp4" />
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                               </video>
                           </apex:outputPanel>
                                <br/>
                   <p style="text-align:center"><apex:outputText value="{!b.Description}" escape="false"></apex:outputText></p><br /><br /><br /><br />
                     </apex:outputPanel>
             </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          </apex:repeat>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <div style="float:right;font-size:16px;"><apex:outputText rendered="{!bwlist2.size > 0}" value="Page 1  "/> <apex:outputLink rendered="{!bwlist2.size > 0}" value="CommunitiesWebinars2" style="text-decoration:underline">2</apex:outputLink></div><br /><br />
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `rendered` condition. Try `{! LEN(b.Video)>0 && NOT(ISNULL(b.Video)) }`.

[You'd *think* ISBLANK would check if a string is blank](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyTzAAK), but the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) states:

> Determines if an expression has a value and returns TRUE if it does not. If it contains a value, this function returns FALSE.

`''` is technically a value...

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried that but it still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try playing around with the rendered expression to verify it's displaying correctly. Throw a few static {'', null} in the array to make sure the condition is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I wasn't declaring the docType as HTML5. Once I added this to the apex page, it worked: docType="html-5.0". Thanks for the ideas!